# A problem that using std::bind to bind a function

Tags: c++, stdbind

I cannot compile the following c++ code, the error shows inside function `call2`, I suppose `call` and `call2` are the same but error occurs on `call2`. I paste the error information to the related code line. Can anyone help me and explain what exactly the signature of the `f` is after executing the std::bind? Also I provide `call3` which is using beast::bind_front_handler to bind the function and it is compiled without error.

BTW: My compiler is clang with c++ standard 14.
Thanks for your time.

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;

void subfunc(int a) { std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl; }

void func(int n, std::string s, std::function<void(int)> &&subf) { subf(n); }

template <typename F>
void call(F &&f2) {
  auto f = std::bind(func, 1, "100", std::forward<F>(f2));
  f();
}

void call2(std::function<void(int)> &&f2) {
  auto f = std::bind(func, 1, "100", std::move(f2));
  f(); // No matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::__bind<void (&)(int, std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::function<void (int)> &&), int, char const (&)[4], std::__1::function<void (int)> >'
}

void call3(std::function<void(int)> &&f2) {
  auto f = beast::bind_front_handler(func, 1, "100", std::move(f2));
  f();
}

int main() {
  call(subfunc);
  call2(subfunc);
  call3(subfunc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows `std::bind` better than me will have a real answer. I would just throw bind out the window and use lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lvalue* cannot be bound to *rvalue reference*.

When you have:

```
void bar(int&&) {}
int i = 0;
bar(i);                // error
```

the last line will not compile.

This is the reason your code fails in second case.

---

`std::bind` takes all passed arguments and copies/moves them into data member of newly generated functor:

```
std::bind(func,arg1,arg2)
```

gives you:

```
class closure1 {
    Arg1 arg1;
    Arg2 arg2;

    void operator()() {
         func(arg1,arg2);
    }
};
```

and it provides also function call operator in which, `arg(s)` are passed by value as *Lvalues* (4th dot in *Member function operator()* section of [`std::bind` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> Otherwise, the ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable
>   object as lvalue argument: the argument vn in the std::invoke call
>   above is simply arg and the corresponding type Vn is T cv &, where cv
>   is the same cv-qualification as that of g.

So this:

```
auto f = std::bind(func, 1, "100", std::forward<F>(f2));
```

generates

```
class closure2 {
       int i = 1;
       std::string s = "100";
       std::forward<void(int)> f;
       void operator()() {
             func(i,s,f);    // [1]
       }
};
```

and in [1] is problem, because `f` as *lvalue* cannot be bound to *rvalue reference* declared in:

```
void func(int n, std::string s, std::function<void(int)> &&subf)
```

you can add another overload taking *lvalue reference*:

```
void func2(int n, std::string s, std::function<void(int)> &subf)
```

and call `bind` with that version of your overloads.

---

There is no problem with `bind_front_handler` because in this implementation all data members of generated functor are forwarded to a target:

```
 func(...,std::forward< std::function<void()> >(f));
```

so `f` will be casted into *rvalue reference*, and `func` can accept this argument.

---

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/CPAhno)

Comment: Got it, std::bind will create a functor object and copy/move the arguments, but bind_front_handler doesn't, just forward the arguments. Thanks!